# SQL Server CE: Code First -- How to handle production model updates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I use SQL CE 4.0 and EF4.2 code-first to create my database locally.  I deploy to the production server and the application is working wonderfully.

Now, I want to deploy an maintenance release that requires changes to the model.

How does one go about modifying the production database without losing production data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox to create a diff script, and run this during deployment of new version.

Answer (score 1):

If migrating to Sql Server (even Express edition) is an option, you could use the Schema Comparison feature of VS Database Projects, which allows you to update a target database without losing any data.
EF 4.3 (which is still beta) will support migrations exactly for that, but I'm not sure if it will support SQL CE either.